# Spring security how to add custom role name

Tags: spring-mvc

In spring security securityContext.xml I have consists different **intercept-url patteren**s like

```
  <intercept-url pattern="/mod1/*" access="hasRole('Mod1_*)" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/mod2/*" access="hasRole('Mod2_*)/>
```

I have different roles starting Mod1_ and Mod2_
But this is not working

Could anyone please help me

Answer (score -1):

Try using hasAnyRole([role1,role2..]) if you have multiple roles like below.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/mod1/*" access="hasAnyRole('Mod1_role1,mod1_role2)" />
```

below is the definition of expressions.

*hasRole([role])-> Returns true if the current principal has the specified role.
hasAnyRole([role1,role2]) -> Returns true if the current principal has any of the supplied roles (given as a comma-separated list of strings)*

Comment: Thank you for your comments but I have many roles starting with Mod1_ so I am looking RolePrefix or RoleVoter but I dont know how to do it .Could anyone please help me for finding one solution..

Comment: Rephrasing question : Spring security should allow only "Mod1" user to access "/mod1" url while "/mod2" will be accessible to user having role "Mod2"